# cloning several hardrives using the dd command

Tags: hard-drive, dd, cloning

I'm developing a software to clone one hard-drive onto several other. I want to clone the content to up to 23 drives at once using `dd` to clone the partition from the source to the targets using `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdc1 bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror` and then repeating this command for `sdd1`, `sde1` etc....

The transfer rate, however, is too low for the need of the application. Typically for a good transfer I have around 100 MB/s, but it goes down to 20 MB/s which slows down the process considerably.

It just allow me to clone up to 12 disks at once. So I split the cloning process to clone to 12 disks for a first step then the remaining for a second step. But that doesn't improve the speed either.

I was wondering if there is something I could do between my two steps.

Comment: what is the command you are using at the moment?

Comment: -ETOOVAGUE.  We can't read your mind and know what commands you are using and what the heck "doesn't work" means.  Also it doesn't make sense to try and clone that many drives at the same time.  Do you really have 23 sata ports?  Using usb enclosures would be even worse; you will never get more than a tiny fraction of the normal throughput of the drives.  Three or four drives at once might make sense, but you really want to have a custom program rather than run 4 instances of `dd` at once and let them fight each other for IO.

Comment: There is also the question of weather dd is really what you want to use... Do you really need to image the empty space?

Comment: I'm using the "dd" command to clone one source partition onto 23 targets partitions.

Comment: I do "sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdc1 bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror" I repeat this command for sdd1, sde1 etc...

Comment: "doesn't work" means the transfert rate is too low for the need of the application. Typically for a good transfert I have around 100 MB/s, when it doesn't work I have a transfert of 20 MB/s which slows down the process considarably.

Comment: All I want is to clone 1 partition to 23 others. That the purpose of my project. Using the "dd" command is the only thing I could come thing after I researched how to clone a partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used tee for specifying multiple targets although I don't recommend exceeding the number of available cores. dd is rather intensive regarding it's use of resources.

`cat source.dd | tee >(dd of=/dev/sda) >(dd of=/dev/sdb) >(dd of=/dev/sdc) | dd of=/dev/sdd`

I did this several years ago for mass duplicating some 4GB USB sticks on USB2 ports. It's been a long time so I don't recall the actual sources I used but it might very well have been https://superuser.com/questions/145516/cloning-single-disk-drive-to-multiple-drives-simultaneously which uses virtually identical code.

Answer (score 2):

You're just being limited by the internal transfer rate of the PCI bus of your computer.  If you want higher speeds, you'll have to stop using a PC and upgrade to server hardware.  For further information see [Intel's specifications sheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/8-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf) for the C220 Series Chipset.

Furthermore, you don't need to develop this software as it already exists: [CloneZilla Server.](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE/) That one however, works using the network, so there you will need an extremely fast server with lots of memory to cache everything and [High-speed Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_Gigabit_Ethernet) or multiple Gigabit cards to be able to serve all the PC's you want to image simultaneously (not forgetting about a high-speed Ethernet switch.

If you still insist on developing your own internal solution, we'll need to have a bit more background information on what you're trying to accomplish as e.g. adding the `--sparse` parameter to your `dd` command *might* speed things up tremendously!  Other options might be `partclone` or `ddrescue` or even LVM snapshots but all these depend on your use case.

Comment: Are you certain it's the PCI bus causing the slowdown? Granted it's part of it, but I wouldn't be so quick to discount CPU load, run top with a few instances of dd running and you'll see what I mean in short order ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek At the time, I took some time to calculate the internal bus speed of a vanilla PC and came to something close.  On a server with different support chips, you can get up to 300 MB/s (theoretical maximum AFAI can remember...) Not doing those calculations again!  **:P  ;-)**

Comment: I'm not suggesting that your calculations were incorrect, just that there are more variables involved ;-)

Comment: :D  Obviously...  But a chain is as weak as it's weakest link.  Do you want me to delete this answer? (upvoted yours as yours gave a solution)

Comment: Of course I don't want you to delete your answer! There's clearly some useful information here. I'm just suggesting that there are other factors involved. The speeds provided led me to believe that these were possible USB3 transfers as 100 MB/s is a bit slower than I've seen over standard SATA ports, but the question doesn't go into enough detail to determine exactly how the drives are connected so that my be an unjustified leap on my part.